# Is it valid to say the function f(n) = n is theta(n)?

Tags: big-o

I am taking a class and we're reviewing time complexity information.

I understand that big o is an upper bound, and omega is a lower bound, and if those are the same then the function is theta(that bound).

Let's say I have the function f(n) = n. Can we say that is is theta(n)?

I think it is because it is O(n) and Omega(n) for C=1 for k>=1, but I wanted to ask to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct. It is a common definition to say that `f \in \Theta(g)` iff `f \in \Omega(g)` and `f \in O(g)`.

Here `f(n) = n` and `g(n) = n`.

To prove both individual parts, `liminf f(n)/g(n) = liminf 1 = 1 > 0` and `limsup g(n)/f(n) = limsup 1 = 1 < \infty`.

In particular `f \in Theta(f)` for all functions `f`.

Note however, that the notation usually uses a big `\Theta`, not a small one.